# Storing data efficiently in MongoLab and in general

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab, database

I have an app that listens to a websocket and it stores usernames/userID's (Usernames are 1-20 bytes, UserID's are 17 bytes). This is not a big deal because it's only one document. However, every round they participate in, it pushes the round ID (24 bytes) and a 'score' decimal value (ex: 1190.0015239999999).

The thing is, there is no limit to how many rounds there are and I can't afford to pay so much per month for mongolab. What's the best way to handle this data?

My thoughts:
- If there is a way to replace the _id: field in mongodb, I will replace it with the userID which is 17 bytes long. Not sure if I can do that though.

- Store user data with timestamps and remove OLD data that has a score value less than 200.
- Cut off user names that are more than 10 characters.
- <s>Completely remove Round ID's (Or replace the _id field with roundId).</s> (Won't work since there are multiple roundID's in each document)
- Round the decimal value to two places.
- Remove Round ID's after 30 days

tl;dr

- Need to store data efficiently < 500 mb in mongo lab
- Documents consists of username(1-20 characters), userid(17 characters), round(Object Array) = [{round Id(24 characters), score(1190.0015239999999)}].

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Document Schema:

```
userID: {type: String},
userName: {type: String},
rounds: [{roundID: String, score: String}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modelling 1:n relationships as embedded document is not the best except for very rare cases. This is because there is a 16MB size limit for BSON documents at the time of this writing.

A better (read more scalable and efficient approach) is to do use [document references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#model-one-to-many-relationships-with-document-references).

First, you need your player data, of course. Here is an example:

```
{
  _id: "SomeUserId",
  name: "SomeName"
}
```

There is no need for an extra `userId` field since each document needs to have a `_id` field with unique values anyway. Contrary to popular belief, this fields value does not have to be an ObjectId. So we already reduced the size you need for your player data by 1/3, if I am not mistaken.

Next, the results of each round:

```
{
  _id: {
    round: "SomeString",
    player: "SomeUserId"
  },
  score: 5,
  createdAt: ISODate("2015-04-13T01:03:04.0002Z")
}
```

A few things are to note here. First and foremost: Do *NOT* use strings to record values. Even grades should rather be stored as corresponding numerical values. Otherwise you can not get averages and alike. I'll show more of that later. We are using a compound field for `_id` here, which is perfectly valid. Furthermore, it will give us a free index optimizing a few of the most likely queries, like "How did player X score in round Y?"

```
db.results.find({"_id.player":"X","_id.round":"Y"})
```

or "What where the results of round Y?"

```
db.results.find({"_id.round":"Y"})
```

or "What we're the scores of Player X in all rounds?"

```
db.results.find({"_id.player":"X"})
```

However, by *not* using a string to save the score, even some nifty stats become rather cheap, for example "What was the average score of round Y?"

```
db.results.aggregate(
  { $match: { "_id.round":"Y" } },
  { $group: { "round":"$_id.round", "averageScore": {$avg:"$score"} }
)
```

or "What is the average score of each player in all rounds?"

```
db.results.aggregate(
  { $group: { "player: "$_id.player", "averageAll": {$avg:"$score"} }
)
```

While you could do these calculation in your application, MongoDB can do them much more efficiently since the data does not have to be send to your app prior to processing it.

Next, for the data expiration. We have a `createdAt` field, of type ISODate. Now, we let MongoDB take care of the rest by creating a [TTL index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-data-from-collections-by-setting-ttl)

```
db.results.ensureIndex(
  { "createdAt":1 },
  { expireAfterSeconds: 60*60*24*30}
)
```

So all in all, this should be pretty much the most efficient way of storing and expiring your data, while improving scalability in the same time.

Comment: Great answer! I'm trying to avoid duplication in data/scores as well because I accidentally connected to the same DB on two different computers (Heroku + Local), causing data to be `$push`'d twice in the rounds array. I could just be careful and watch out next time I launch my web app.

Comment: One more thing, how do you link the documents? I'm guessing you just give them the same field name, but you didn't do that for _id in rounds. Aggregation is fairly new to me, if I wanted to display every round + their score on a site, could you use aggregation easily for that?

Comment: Advice: Use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead of `$push` for the array. As for the linking: simply use the value of an `_id` in another field and query for it. ;)

Comment: I tried doing that and I was getting errors so I reverted back because I was scared I would messup my data. It said something about the item not being an Array.

Answer (score 0):

So currently you are storing **three** data points in the array for each record.

_id: false will prevent mongoose from automatically creating an id for the document.  If you don't need roundID, then you can use the following which only stores **one** data point in the array:

```
round[{_id:false, score:String}]
```

Otherwise if roundID actually has meaning, use the following which stores **two** data points in the array:

```
round[{_id:false, roundID: string, score:String}]
```

Lastly, if you just need an ID for reference purposes, use the following, which will store **two** data points in the array - a random id and the score:

```
round[{score:String}]
```

Comment: Where do I do this "_id: false"? I don't really understand #2. The whole point of this is to store a history of scores. I'm using "findoneandupdate" with the options "new: true, upsert: true" to create a new document if the userID is not found.

Comment: See updated answer for where to put _id: false.  So you might already know this but Mongoose automatically creates an '_id' for a document when it is created.  So it sounds like you are just pushing new round scores in the array.  If you don't need to keep track of them, then just use what I have above.  Otherwise, use 'round[{score:String}] because you will have an _id created automatically.  For the second one, I removed it because I thought you were saying that it was creating a duplicate document.  My bad.

Comment: I set _id to userid and rounded using (Math.round(num * 100) / 100). Thank you for your suggestions. I had to clear the entire DB because I didn't feel like removing the userId field and setting the previous _id fields to userId's.